# SSRS to preserve excel formula

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I realize this is the official answer from microsoft, that this feature is dropped in SQL 2008. But I am wondering if anyone come up with a clever workaround?

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/488517/ssrs-2008-export-formulas-to-excel

In the link above one of the work around is to use "'=A1+B1"
Then once in excel just replace all and remove the single quote to make the formula work.

What I don't understand from the suggested workaround is that all the row will have A1+B1 wouldn't it? Or am I misunderstood this? How can I get the row to auto increment?

Comment: Its not free but I believe aspose does what you are attempting, http://www.aspose.com/reporting-services/excel-component.aspx

Comment: Check out my workaround solution that I created for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016094/3262289.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct in the way you interpreted it but one user had suggested to use **RowNumber** to increment the row number in the formula.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowFormulas.Value,"'=A" & RowNumber("myQuery") & "+B" & RowNumber("myQuery"),Fields!C.Value)
```

You'd still need to go into the report and remove the apostrophes.

I did something similar by using **SSIS** to create the actual formula in an Excel sheet with a VB Script task.

```
    ExcelFormula = "=SUM(" & SumColumn & "45:" & SumColumn & Row.ToString & ")"
    Worksheet.Cells(Row, Column).Formula = ExcelFormula
```

Comment: what is myQuery referring to? is it the dataset? I thought that "IIF statement" in the suggestion was regarding to show the formula or show the number calculation result. but I'll try to see if that will get me the rownumber. thanks

Comment: Yes - the IIF was whether to display the formula or the static value. The formula part was **"'=A" & RowNumber("myQuery") & "+B" & RowNumber("myQuery")**. I think his **myQuery** was a group in a matrix. If you're just using a regular table, you should be able to use RowNumber(). Remember to add the extra rows for your header (and any other rows before the data). If you have a one-line header, **RowNumber()** of **1** would start on **Row 2** of the Excel sheet.